# getting weird error in sessions in express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express framework and here is what I have in the `server.js` file:

```
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require( 'express' ), //Web framework
path = require( 'path' ), //Utilities for dealing with file paths
mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); //MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express();

// Configure server
app.configure( function() {

app.use( express.bodyParser() );
app.use( express.methodOverride() );
app.use( app.router );
app.use(express.session({secret:'thisismysupersecret'}));
app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'site') ) );
app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
app.post("/verifyLogin",function(request,response){
var usr=request.body.username;
var pass=request.body.password;
//request.session.email=usr;
response.redirect('dashboard');
});

//Start server
var port = 3000;
app.listen( port, function() {
console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env);
});
```

When I navigate to localhost:3000 I get this error

> 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You're missing the `cookieParser` middleware:

```
...
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use(express.session({secret:'thisismysupersecret'}));
...
```

(since sessions are implemented using cookies).

Comment: and how to use session variables? i use request.session.email=usr  as commented in the code but it throws error of undefined...

Comment: You need to move `app.use(app.router)` to below all your routes.

Comment: yes it worked. Can you help me understand this concept of adding middleware stack? i mean how the order makes the difference and why? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I was incorrect: `app.use(app.router)` should be below `app.use(express.session(...))`, that'll suffice. The reason is that middlewares are called in order of adding them, if you want to use sessions in your routes, the sessions middleware needs to be added before your router, otherwise the session middleware never gets called (because the middleware handling your routes was added earlier).

Comment: I had this out of sequence, flipping to this order fixed the issue for me... Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me except now you need to `npm install cookie-parser` then `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')` and add it as `app.use(cookieParser())`

Comment: @Abby yeah, with Express 4 various previously built-in middleware functionality has now been moved to external modules.

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same problem.

be sure to calling

```
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
```

before

`app.use(express.session({secret:'thisismysupersecret'}));`